# How do I handle a generic field in JaxB?

Tags: xml, generics, serialization, jaxb

I have a parameterized class with a generic field like this and I'm trying to figure how how to write an adapter that will handle the generic field:

```
public class Thing<T> {

    private T options;

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    @XmlNullPolicy(isSetPerformedForAbsentNode = false, nullRepresentationForXml = XmlMarshalNullRepresentation.XSI_NIL)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OptionsAdapter.class)
    @Override
    public void setOptions(final T options) {
        this.options = options;
    }
}
```

I started writing the adapter class and then realized, I have no idea how to do this:

```
public class OptionsAdapter<T> extends XmlAdapter<Object, T> {

    @Override
    public T unmarshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        //What do I do to identify the actual type of the object?
    }

    @Override
    public Object marshal(T v) throws Exception {
        //???
    }
}
```

I've found lots of information about how to handle generic collections. Nothing on how to handle a simple generic field.